# Custom select box scroll bars with jquery css - Is there a cross-browser compatible solution?

Tags: jquery, css, select, listbox, scrollbars

I've searched for several hours now and have found 0 examples of a  box with custom scrollbars/arrows. I could find a few references of people talking about how its impossible and the best idea is to not do it.

Other than those bits of advice, is there a cross-browser compatible solution for this? Does anyone know any sites currently using a custom scrollbar for a sized  so maybe I can look at that code?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the `<select>` element is replaced on-the-fly with a crafted set of `<div>`s and `<ul>` and `<li>`, making it hidden, and with some event delegation on your `<li>`s so you can select the real option in the hidden `<select>`.

for example, it would look like this:

```js
 $(function(){
    $('select:visible').each(function(){
       var 
          $this = $(this), 
          $select = $('<div/>', {
            'css':{
              'display': 'inline-block',
              'position': 'relative'
            }
          }),
          $items, $ul,
          $display = $('<p/>');

       $this.hide();
       $items = $this.find('option').map(function(){ return '<li data-value="'+this.value+'">'+$(this).text()+'</li>'; }).get().join(''); // map the options from the select in an html string

       $ul = $('<ul/>', {
         'css':{
           'display':'none',
           'position':'absolute',
           'bottom': '0',
           'width': 'inherit'
         }
       });

       $ul.append($items); // append the items from the original select

       $select.append($display).append($ul); // create the "fake" select
       $this.before($select);

       $ul.on('click', 'li', function(e){
          $display.text($(e.target).text()); // set the text of your select
          $this.val($(e.target).data('value')); // set the value of the original select that is hidden
       });

       $select.click(function(){
         $ul.toggle(); // show/hide the items
       });
    });
 });
```

I created this code now but haven't tested it, but thats the idea. All the styling (CSS) is up to you. Just make sure to set the class for the LIs to have `white-space: nowrap;` so it can expand as needed.

Now with all this custom HTML, you can add your own arrow, and for the scrollbars, you could use an existing solution, like jScrollpane and attach to your `$ul` that holds your items, reminding to set a `max-height` css style to it to be effective.